# ajax get tha value of input type select option

Tags: javascript

how to get the value of an input select option selected ,  I have a form with select option. If an option is selected with the value "example_5" I want it to get the value of an selected option

```
var tow; 
var str;



     var e = document.getElementById("street");
     str= e.value;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the code you need to use:

```
var e = document.getElementById("street");
var str;
for(var i = 0; i <e.children.length; i++){
    var opt = e.children[i];
    if (opt.selected == true){
        str = opt.value;
    }
}
```